# How do I switch from Ubuntu to Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu

I have an installation disc of Ubuntu 12.04 but now I need to install Lubuntu 13.04. What are the steps to be followed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Can you please state your goal more precisely? Do you want to install Lubuntu 13.04 to a new, independent partition and dual-boot with Ubuntu 12.04? Or upgrade the *current* Ubuntu 12.04 with Lubuntu 13.04? Or perhaps wipe out Ubuntu and perform a clean install of Lubuntu? Dual boot and wipe out approaches are pretty straightforward, but upgrade in same partition (keeping programs, settings, etc)  can be a lot trickier.

Answer (score -1):

You can either install Ubuntu from the disk you have and then install the `lubuntu-desktop` meta-package.

Or just grab and install from a Lubuntu CD. The bandwidth required will be similar.